# Does anybody recognize this MTB frame?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

I just got this frame for a few bucks and I wonder if it is from a known manufacturer or not. I often find bikes with similar design aspects, but not this frame. There was also a Marzocchi 55 ETA from 2008 sitting in there, so I guess the frame has a similar age.

[image]

---

Edit: Assembled bike, after a paint job.

[image: In-line image from comment.]

Comment: No idea - the external reservoir on the shock looks above the normal cheap coil shock.  Rear drop outs seem to be a space-frame design which looks neat.   The frame has dings and wangs so has seen some hard use - check it carefully all over before assembling... use a bright light from several angles to explore for cracks.

Comment: thanks anyways. I thought that too, that it's not looking too bad from how the frame is built. and good tip with the cracks. my plan right now is to do a new paintjob and get new bearings before doing anything with this frame, so I may see the cracks better after sanding the old paint down

Comment: Use https://derailleurhanger.com/shop to compare derailleur hangers for possible candidates.  bikepedia.com can help.  Looks like it might be a tapered head set, if so, narrows down year of manufacture to post 2010(ish), if not, most likely pre 2010.

Comment: For cracks, the sound from light tapping with a screw driver can be helpful.

Comment: the idea with the hanger is insanely good, thanks for that. a good site in general. haven't found the exact frame yet, but I dig into it deeper tomorrow- this is the first hope so far

Comment: Man, I've been looking for matching frame for hours at a time on and off since the question was posted, but found absolutely nothing that ticks all the frame features. There's a lot of similar frames, not none are exactly like this one. My Google-fu was not enough.

Comment: Question is 10 months old - @tonnenmeter did you find anything out via other sources?

Comment: You can narrow it down quite a bit since given the approximate year, the Horst link means it's either a Specialized or one of the handful of companies to license the design from them. (That's true in the US at least, not sure if there are any major exceptions worldwide.)

Comment: Given the forks that came off and the size of the shock we can narrow it to the 'all mountain' genre.  Shock mounting bears a definite resemblance to a transition bottlerocket.

Comment: The climbmax shock isnt easy to find information on, but seems to have been made by KS (kind shock).  I found a reference to the cx1.0 being from 2008, so assume cx3.0 is probably rather newer.

Comment: sorry @Klaster_1, I gave my search up long time ago. I also asked on pinkbike and a german forum, was looking in manufacturer prospects of several years, tried different derailleur hanger sites and tried the wildest google searches. I found quite a few frames that looked even closer like this one than the bottlerocket, but every damn frame was different in some way. this frame is a mystery, maybe some chinese stuff that is probably impossible to find

Comment: @tonnenmeter so would your appreciation for this frame change if you knew what brand it was?   Will/did you build it up to a rideable bike ?

Comment: @Criggie no it wouldn't change at all! but I think it's good to know what you are dealing with. and yes I built a bike that I love, [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XNKTYIhfphdoLngpmdPOLkYGolT72gxz) a picture of it

Answer (score 4):

If I had this frame, I would look again at those frames that most resembled it. Rather than a tiny manufacturer that nobody anywhere can recall, it's much more likely that a relatively sophisticated frame like yours is a pre-production model, or a sponsored rider version that differs significantly from the commercially sold model. That's why you can't find that exact frame elsewhere in order to identify it.

I think you've already seen a picture of the descendant or tweaked version of this frame, but you didn't realise the connection, you only noticed the differences.

The frame having no frame number is another pointer to it being most likely a custom-built for a pro rider or being a development model, not a production bike. Some machines in these categories have no serial no. at all, some have a low number, or just initials, or a combination of both, often stamped in an unusual place on the frame.

Someone who was around the racing circuit when this frame was current might remember it - the marks of extensive use seem to indicate that it might have been raced at some time.

Comment: Interesting thought, there’s a first time for everything!

Comment: good input! the frame also has no frame number under the bottom bracket (but it doesn't look like it was removed either haha) so there might be a chance for that